# Removing UIView from view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3, uilabel

I have a UIView and a few labels and buttons which are built in a function menuState. When I click a button in the menuState function, it takes us out of the function into menuPlayButtonClicked() function. In this function, I'm trying to hide the labels and the UIView which I built in the menuState function because the game is beginning. Using menuView.isHidden = true is not doing it. menuView.removeFromSuperView() isn't doing it either. I tried declaring these views and labels globally with a let menuView = UIView() as well, but it still isn't removing it. What am I missing? I can still see the labels and UIView in the background underneath the game components.

```
func menuState() {

//Build the menu box
    let menuView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 400))
    menuView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "background.png")!)
    self.view.addSubview(menuView)
    menuView.layer.zPosition = 1;
    menuView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    menuView.isHidden = false

...

Also some code for a button here, which takes us to the setupGame function when clicked

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `menuView` object which is declared globally is not the same one which is created locally inside the function named "menuState()". So, don't declare another local instance, you may try following way -

```
menuState() {
  menuView = ...   // don't use `let` or 'var' again here, but reference the same global variable that you will use later to hide
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Does it make more sense to use .isHidden or to remove it from the superview, in terms of hiding menu options

Comment: That requires few more context to answer. But as a short answer "isHidden" will be a good fit for you here.

Answer (score 1):

The "menuView" in two functions is not the one object, just do not use "let" .
By the way , if you will show menuView again in the future , use "isHidden" ,if you will never use it again , use "removeFromSuperView" to free your memory.